# How to add icon into navigation drawer

Tags: java, android-studio

I blur with the complicate code which is all customize navigation drawer. I just want create a simple navigation with icon only and it using fragment to swap the the content to be display when user click the navigation list.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
        implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

    /**
     * Fragment managing the behaviors, interactions and presentation of the navigation drawer.
     */
    private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;

    /**
     * Used to store the last screen title. For use in {@link #restoreActionBar()}.
     */
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
        mTitle = getTitle();

        // Set up the drawer.
        mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
                R.id.navigation_drawer,
                (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));
    }

    @Override
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
        android.app.Fragment objFragment = null;

        switch (position){
            case 0:
                objFragment = new Overview();
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section0);

                break;
            case 1:
                objFragment = new Income();
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section1);
                break;
            case 2:
                objFragment = new Expenses();
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section2);
                break;
            case 3:
                objFragment = new Category();
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section3);
                break;
            case 4:
                objFragment = new CashConverter();
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section4);
                break;
            case 5:
                objFragment = new History();
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section5);
                break;
        }


        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, objFragment)
                .commit();
    }

    public void onSectionAttached(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section0);
                break;
            case 1:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section1);
                break;
            case 2:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section2);
                break;
            case 3:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section3);
                break;
            case 4:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section4);
                break;
            case 5:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section5);
                break;
        }
    }

    public void restoreActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
            // Only show items in the action bar relevant to this screen
            // if the drawer is not showing. Otherwise, let the drawer
            // decide what to show in the action bar.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            restoreActionBar();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

PlaceholderFragment

```
/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
     * number.
     */
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        ((MainActivity) activity).onSectionAttached(
                getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there are 2 ways to do this.
 1. you add the item for the navigation drawer manually.
 2. still use list adapter but with overridden `getView` method and take advantage of TextView compound drawables. You can search for `setCompoundDrawablesRelative` for more info.

I'm not gonna post the first option since it would need to change many part of the code, but here is the example for the second option.

Find the `onCreateView` method in your **NavigationDrawerFragment class** and adapt this pseudocode below to your code.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mDrawerListView = <get your navigation drawer list view here or leave it like the original>
    mDrawerListView.setOnItemClickListener(<for the click listener, again leave it like the original>);

    final LayoutInflater inflater1 = inflater; //this is for the child AdapterView to access the inflater

    mDrawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            <get your context here>,
            R.layout.simple_activated_list,
            R.id.item,
            <your array of items to be listed in the drawer>
        ){
        @Override
        public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
            super.getView(pos, convertView, parent);
            if(convertView == null) {
                // if the view is null, you need to inflate the view explicitly
                convertView = inflater1.inflate(R.layout.simple_activated_list, parent, false);
            }

            TextView tv = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.item);
            String str = getItem(pos); // for displaying your menu text, since you have overridden it
            Drawable d; // for setting up your icon and its size
            float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
            tv.setText(str); // set the text
            // you can branch out by menu name or menu order (pos)
            switch(str){
                case "Your menu text":
                    // your specific menu item
                    d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_history);
                    break;
                default:
                    // else
                    d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_arrow);
                    break;
            }
            // set it to 24dp x 24dp
            d.setBounds(0,0,Math.round(24*density),Math.round(24*density));
            tv.setCompoundDrawablesRelative(d, null, null, null); // set the icon

            return convertView;
        }
    });

    mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(mCurrentSelectedPosition, true);
    return mDrawerListView;
}
```

hope that helps

Comment: Thank you so much, but i still got some error when i applying this code, that maybe just the workflow i totally not understand. Sorry that i still poor in android.

Comment: you need to change a few thing of the code to match your code, especially things in <> bracket (except for the <String> after the AdapterView) , compare it to your code, and replace the same part of this pseudocode to match yours